# TextMeshPro font doesn't change

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity-ui

I'm using TMP in my project. I have downloaded font - Quanelas. I'm creating font prefab via Font Asset Creator. When I'm trying to switch my font it staying default.

It's how numbers, for example, look like:

[image]

But must be like:

[image]

I also noticed, that in SubMesh font still staying default:

[image]

I think that is thre reason, but I can't change font in SubMesh

Help and Sorry for my English :D

Comment: Not sure I really get it.  Drag your new Quanelas font into the TMP_Sub Mesh UI

Comment: you need to create a font asset from the font file and then use it in your text mesh
https://learn.unity.com/tutorial/textmesh-pro-font-asset-creation